# Populating columns of one table with rows from another. Based on criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Good morning.  Sorry for the long post but I am getting completely stomped on how to accomplish this properly.

I have a user submitted file for financial forecast by project and general ledger account by month for  up to 15 years out   that gets loaded into a flat staging table.

```
--Flat Staging Table with user submitted forecast

    CREATE TABLE dbo.[STG_fcst](
        [PROJ_ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [ACT_ID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [FC_DATE] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
        [AMT_USD] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
        [UPDATEID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [DTSTAMP] [datetime] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

Only one column for Dates.  Users just provide year and month. On the other end I have  a pivoted table that is segregated by forecast folder  that looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[FORECAST](
    [PLANKEY] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,--Plankey=Folderkey+project_id+proj_id
    [PROJ_ID] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ACT_ID] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_JAN] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_FEB] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_MAR] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_APR] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_MAY] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_JUN] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_JUL] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_AUG] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_SEP] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_OCT] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_NOV] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_ACT_DEC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_JAN] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_FEB] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_MAR] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_APR] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_MAY] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_JUN] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_JUL] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_AUG] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_SEP] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_OCT] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_NOV] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y1_FC_DEC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_JAN] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_FEB] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_MAR] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_APR] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_MAY] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_JUN] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_JUL] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_AUG] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_SEP] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_OCT] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_NOV] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y2_FC_DEC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y3_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y4_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y5_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y6_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y7_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y8_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y9_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y10_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y11_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y12_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y13_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y14_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [Y15_FC] [numeric](20, 2) NULL,
    [UPDATEID] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [DTSTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_FORECAST] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PLANKEY] ASC,
    [PROJ_ID] ASC,
    [ACT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

It is a 15 year forecast table segregated by plan_key which denotes basically forecast folder(i.e. Jan Fcst, May fcst etc.)
First two calendar years  for each forecast folder is by month years 3 to 15 have to be  aggregated by year.

I also have a table that tells me for each folder what  the first forecasted month should be and a counter of how many month need to be by month so if the first forecasted month is Feb then counter is 24 if  March then 23.

```
CREATE table dbo.[FOLDER_FCST_DT_XREF_VW]
    (FOLDERKEY  varchar(255),
    (FOLDERNAME VARCHAR(255),
FCST_BASE_DATE DATE,
CTR_STOP INT)
```

So the question is how I would take data in a staging table and load it into forecast table I need to start loading into appropriate bucket based on the forecast base date so If Base Date is March 2016 I need to grab March 2016 from the staging table ignoring any prior month if any put that into Y1_FC_MAR column for the particular project/account combination. Increment that start date by one month however many times counter goes in xref table updating the rest of the monthly columns in Forecast table after counter runs out need to aggregate staging table by year for those dates and populate yearly buckets.

Here is sample data for the tables.

```
--Data for Folder Table
insert into dbo.[FOLDER_FCST_DT_XREF_VW]
(FOLDERKEY,FOLDERNAME,FCST_BASE_DATE,CTR_STOP)
Values
('AA99','Study Scenario Estimates (2016)',2016-06-01,'19'),
('AB05','2015 Feb Refresh',2015-02-01,'23'),
('AB06','2015 March Refresh',2015-03-01,'22'),
('AB07','2015 May Forecast',2015-04-01,'21'),
('AB08','2015 May Refresh',2015-05-01,'20'),
('AB09','2015 Jun Refresh',2015-06-01,'19'),
('AB10','2015 Aug Forecast',2015-07-01,'18'),
('AB11','2015 Aug Refresh',2015-08-01,'17'),
('AB12','2015 Sept Refresh',2015-09-01,'16'),
('AB13','2015 Nov Forecast',2015-10-01,'15'),
('AB14','2015 Dec Refresh',2015-12-01,'13'),
('AB16','2015 Actuals',2016-01-01,'24'),
('AB17','2016 Feb Tally',2016-02-01,'23'),
('AB18','2016 Feb Refresh',2016-02-01,'23'),
('AB19','2016 March Refresh',2016-03-01,'22'),
('AB20','2016 May Forecast',2016-04-01,'21'),
('AB21','2016 June Refresh',2016-06-01,'19'),
('AB22','2016 Aug Forecast',2016-07-01,'18'),
('AB23','2016 Sep Refresh',2016-09-01,'16'),
('AB24','2016 Nov Forecast',2016-10-01,'15'),
('AB25','2016 Dec Refresh',2016-11-01,'14')

--Data for Staging Table
insert into dbo.[STG_fcst](Proj_id,Act_Id,FC_Date)
values

('Project51','G1000','2017.03',150),
('Project7','G1000','2017.03',1867726.45),
('Project8','G1000','2017.03',168827.4),
('Project10','G1000','2017.03',38070.41),
('Project32','G1000','2017.03',13574.25),
('Project44','G1000','2017.03',23405.95),
('Project45','G1000','2017.03',164787.89),
('Project55','G1000','2017.03',76364),
('Project50','G1000','2017.03',16714.98),
('Project59','G1000','2017.03',104135.17),
('Project74','G1000','2017.03',65706),
('Project73','G1000','2017.03',5775),
('Project79','G1000','2017.03',91918.11),
('Project108','G1000','2017.03',27279),
('Project110','G1000','2017.03',142071.75),
('Project16','G1000','2017.03',45931.49),
('Project17','G1000','2017.03',141555.9),
('Project63','G1000','2017.03',423716.64),
('Project72','G1000','2017.03',25000),
('Project18','G1006','2017.03',100000),
('Project130','G1000','2017.03',92710.75),
('Project106','G1006','2017.03',44209.5),
('Project36','G1000','2017.03',207394.05),
('Project93','G1006','2017.03',63300),
('Project129','G1000','2017.03',29137.75),
('Project20','G1006','2017.03',34584),
('Project38','G1000','2017.03',57324.15),
('Project22','G1000','2017.03',169847.4),
('Project28','G1000','2017.03',49000),
('Project131','G1000','2017.03',NULL),
('Project35','G1000','2017.03',81950),
('Project57','G1006','2017.03',700),
('Project95','G1000','2017.03',21500),
('Project29','G1005','2017.03',51000),
('Project84','G1006','2017.03',47994),
('Project128','G1000','2017.03',75000),
('Project103','G1000','2017.03',37500),
('Project89','G1006','2017.03',20500),
('Project88','G1006','2017.03',42444),
('Project99','G1006','2017.03',42500),
('Project47','G1000','2017.03',56086),
('Project69','G1006','2017.03',51107),
('Project70','G1000','2017.03',14400),
('Project82','G1006','2017.03',42382),
('Project102','G1006','2017.03',7823.55),
('Project56','G1006','2017.03',8749),
('Project78','G1006','2017.03',31867),
('Project76','G1006','2017.03',20000),
('Project5','G1000','2017.03',84764),
('Project105','G1000','2017.03',3630),
('Project7','G1000','2017.06',1886317.88),
('Project8','G1000','2017.06',133876.9),
('Project65','G1000','2017.06',36573.78),
('Project12','G1000','2017.06',20000),
('Project13','G1006','2017.06',154300),
('Project45','G1000','2017.06',275020),
('Project55','G1000','2017.06',31994.89),
('Project48','G1000','2017.06',50000),
('Project50','G1000','2017.06',67140.72),
('Project59','G1000','2017.06',21168),
('Project74','G1000','2017.06',54755),
('Project73','G1000','2017.06',3000),
('Project79','G1000','2017.06',7993.3),
('Project80','G1000','2017.06',250000),
('Project104','G1000','2017.06',125000),
('Project110','G1000','2017.06',94714.5),
('Project118','G1000','2017.06',50000),
('Project115','G1000','2017.06',25000),
('Project15','G1000','2017.06',46000),
('Project16','G1000','2017.06',57639.53),
('Project58','G1000','2017.06',100000),
('Project17','G1000','2017.06',116003),
('Project63','G1000','2017.06',239148.28),
('Project126','G1000','2017.06',25000),
('Project18','G1006','2017.06',71876.64),
('Project130','G1000','2017.06',92710.75),
('Project106','G1006','2017.06',19438),
('Project36','G1000','2017.06',207394.05),
('Project93','G1006','2017.06',50000),
('Project129','G1000','2017.06',29137.75),
('Project20','G1006','2017.06',19056),
('Project21','G1006','2017.06',50000),
('Project38','G1000','2017.06',43953.56),
('Project22','G1000','2017.06',158935.4),
('Project28','G1000','2017.06',49000),
('Project46','G1000','2017.06',44175.23),
('Project42','G1000','2017.06',905600),
('Project131','G1000','2017.06',181666.67),
('Project35','G1000','2017.06',81945.19),
('Project26','G1000','2017.06',10000),
('Project112','G1000','2017.06',20000),
('Project85','G1006','2017.06',40000),
('Project92','G1006','2017.06',67143),
('Project113','G1000','2017.06',90000),
('Project83','G1006','2017.06',5000),
('Project29','G1005','2017.06',45000),
('Project103','G1000','2017.06',37500),
('Project87','G1006','2017.06',20000),
('Project121','G1000','2017.06',75000),
('Project119','G1000','2017.06',5000),
('Project120','G1000','2017.06',3000),
('Project123','G1000','2017.06',75000),
('Project122','G1000','2017.06',15000),
('Project124','G1000','2017.06',15000),
('Project125','G1000','2017.06',3000),
('Project47','G1000','2017.06',15160),
('Project107','G1000','2017.06',27000),
('Project69','G1006','2017.06',22550),
('Project70','G1000','2017.06',30000),
('Project102','G1006','2017.06',86059.05),
('Project78','G1006','2017.06',98515),
('Project51','G1000','2017.09',60000),
('Project7','G1000','2017.09',1903395.51),
('Project8','G1000','2017.09',117317.6),
('Project65','G1000','2017.09',36573.78),
('Project9','G1000','2017.09',192479.65),
('Project10','G1000','2017.09',42268.65),
('Project11','G1000','2017.09',16745),
('Project34','G1000','2017.09',75000),
('Project48','G1000','2017.09',75000),
('Project73','G1000','2017.09',3000),
('Project80','G1000','2017.09',150000),
('Project104','G1000','2017.09',100000),
('Project110','G1000','2017.09',78928.75),
('Project118','G1000','2017.09',75000),
('Project114','G1000','2017.09',125000),
('Project115','G1000','2017.09',50000),
('Project117','G1000','2017.09',150000),
('Project116','G1000','2017.09',40000),
('Project15','G1000','2017.09',25000),
('Project58','G1000','2017.09',100000),
('Project17','G1000','2017.09',97372.66),
('Project63','G1000','2017.09',115052.53),
('Project72','G1000','2017.09',100000),
('Project126','G1000','2017.09',25000),
('Project130','G1000','2017.09',92710.75),
('Project36','G1000','2017.09',207394.05),
('Project93','G1006','2017.09',100780),
('Project129','G1000','2017.09',29137.75),
('Project20','G1006','2017.09',25000),
('Project38','G1000','2017.09',47953.56),
('Project22','G1000','2017.09',700641.24),
('Project66','G1000','2017.09',9631.35),
('Project131','G1000','2017.09',181666.67),
('Project112','G1000','2017.09',30000),
('Project85','G1006','2017.09',10000),
('Project92','G1006','2017.09',52143),
('Project113','G1000','2017.09',100000),
('Project29','G1005','2017.09',25000),
('Project84','G1006','2017.09',80604),
('Project103','G1000','2017.09',37500),
('Project87','G1006','2017.09',20000),
('Project121','G1000','2017.09',75000),
('Project119','G1000','2017.09',10000),
('Project123','G1000','2017.09',75000),
('Project122','G1000','2017.09',35000),
('Project124','G1000','2017.09',30000),
('Project125','G1000','2017.09',17000),
('Project47','G1000','2017.09',30520),
('Project107','G1000','2017.09',28000),
('Project69','G1006','2017.09',48389),
('Project82','G1006','2017.09',42382),
('Project102','G1006','2017.09',86059.05),
('Project78','G1006','2017.09',32839),
('Project5','G1000','2017.09',50858.4),
('Project7','G1000','2017.12',1843590.45),
('Project8','G1000','2017.12',36933),
('Project65','G1000','2017.12',18286.96),
('Project10','G1000','2017.12',792277.82),
('Project11','G1000','2017.12',15000),
('Project34','G1000','2017.12',75000),
('Project45','G1000','2017.12',308237.74),
('Project48','G1000','2017.12',75000),
('Project73','G1000','2017.12',3000),
('Project80','G1000','2017.12',150000),
('Project104','G1000','2017.12',100000),
('Project118','G1000','2017.12',150000),
('Project114','G1000','2017.12',125000),
('Project115','G1000','2017.12',75000),
('Project117','G1000','2017.12',150000),
('Project116','G1000','2017.12',80000),
('Project15','G1000','2017.12',31000),
('Project16','G1000','2017.12',9006.17),
('Project58','G1000','2017.12',100000),
('Project31','G1000','2017.12',41428.41),
('Project17','G1000','2017.12',54301.94),
('Project63','G1000','2017.12',55555.63),
('Project72','G1000','2017.12',200000),
('Project126','G1000','2017.12',25000),
('Project19','G1000','2017.12',561577.32),
('Project130','G1000','2017.12',92710.75),
('Project106','G1006','2017.12',4900),
('Project36','G1000','2017.12',224050.93),
('Project129','G1000','2017.12',29137.75),
('Project20','G1006','2017.12',25000),
('Project86','G1000','2017.12',2000),
('Project21','G1006','2017.12',50000),
('Project38','G1000','2017.12',63851.19),
('Project22','G1000','2017.12',125000),
('Project24','G1006','2017.12',50000),
('Project46','G1000','2017.12',44175.23),
('Project42','G1000','2017.12',59921),
('Project131','G1000','2017.12',181666.67),
('Project26','G1000','2017.12',10000),
('Project112','G1000','2017.12',50000),
('Project85','G1006','2017.12',45000),
('Project92','G1006','2017.12',52143),
('Project113','G1000','2017.12',100000),
('Project83','G1006','2017.12',5000),
('Project41','G1000','2017.12',500),
('Project29','G1005','2017.12',20000),
('Project84','G1006','2017.12',67916),
('Project103','G1000','2017.12',37500),
('Project87','G1006','2017.12',10000),
('Project121','G1000','2017.12',75000),
('Project119','G1000','2017.12',25000),
('Project123','G1000','2017.12',100000),
('Project122','G1000','2017.12',30000),
('Project124','G1000','2017.12',15000),
('Project125','G1000','2017.12',10000),
('Project47','G1000','2017.12',21400),
('Project102','G1006','2017.12',86059.05),
('Project78','G1006','2017.12',22000),
('Project5','G1000','2017.12',60394.35),
('Project51','G1000','2018.12',80000),
('Project7','G1000','2018.12',6899543.92),
('Project8','G1000','2018.12',81123.9),
('Project65','G1000','2018.12',105950.62),
('Project11','G1000','2018.12',31007),
('Project34','G1000','2018.12',150000),
('Project48','G1000','2018.12',100000),
('Project104','G1000','2018.12',100000),
('Project118','G1000','2018.12',525000),
('Project115','G1000','2018.12',150000),
('Project117','G1000','2018.12',250000),
('Project116','G1000','2018.12',80000),
('Project16','G1000','2018.12',60576.98),
('Project58','G1000','2018.12',120000),
('Project31','G1000','2018.12',141714.83),
('Project17','G1000','2018.12',551764.83),
('Project63','G1000','2018.12',586148.48),
('Project72','G1000','2018.12',360000),
('Project126','G1000','2018.12',50000),
('Project19','G1000','2018.12',326584.77),
('Project130','G1000','2018.12',370843),
('Project36','G1000','2018.12',846233.08),
('Project129','G1000','2018.12',116551),
('Project20','G1006','2018.12',70000),
('Project21','G1006','2018.12',400000),
('Project38','G1000','2018.12',120000),
('Project22','G1000','2018.12',930069.86),
('Project24','G1006','2018.12',287500),
('Project46','G1000','2018.12',13382.28),
('Project42','G1000','2018.12',533701),
('Project131','G1000','2018.12',545000),
('Project112','G1000','2018.12',200000),
('Project29','G1005','2018.12',150000),
('Project84','G1006','2018.12',214133),
('Project128','G1000','2018.12',75000),
('Project82','G1006','2018.12',84764),
('Project102','G1006','2018.12',388942.2),
('Project5','G1000','2018.12',144310.71),
('Project51','G1000','2019.12',60000),
('Project7','G1000','2019.12',4782397.34),
('Project31','G1000','2019.12',78014.19),
('Project17','G1000','2019.12',522097.43),
('Project63','G1000','2019.12',504668.12),
('Project72','G1000','2019.12',244500),
('Project19','G1000','2019.12',600528.16),
('Project36','G1000','2019.12',190405.42),
('Project20','G1006','2019.12',70000),
('Project21','G1006','2019.12',500000),
('Project38','G1000','2019.12',180000),
('Project22','G1000','2019.12',973906.04),
('Project24','G1006','2019.12',500000),
('Project42','G1000','2019.12',335626),
('Project112','G1000','2019.12',200000),
('Project29','G1005','2019.12',150000),
('Project128','G1000','2019.12',75000),
('Project7','G1000','2020.12',1449182.69),
('Project17','G1000','2020.12',522097.43),
('Project63','G1000','2020.12',473304.12),
('Project72','G1000','2020.12',244500),
('Project19','G1000','2020.12',352075.36),
('Project36','G1000','2020.12',387872.15),
('Project20','G1006','2020.12',20000),
('Project21','G1006','2020.12',500000),
('Project38','G1000','2020.12',180000),
('Project22','G1000','2020.12',350673.36),
('Project24','G1006','2020.12',600000),
('Project42','G1000','2020.12',35952),
('Project29','G1005','2020.12',150000),
('Project17','G1000','2021.12',522097.43),
('Project63','G1000','2021.12',457054.12),
('Project72','G1000','2021.12',244500),
('Project19','G1000','2021.12',648372.55),
('Project21','G1006','2021.12',500000),
('Project24','G1006','2021.12',600000)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought about doing this with dynamic SQL, but I think you can do it static

What you want to do is pivot and aggregate. Since it is a highly specialized pivot, I would not try to do it with the Pivot command. So I pivot by using aggregations and group by.

Here is my attempt. I cannot fill out UPDATEID and DTSTMp, and the plankey apparently has to be made by using both project_id and proj_id, and you have only supplied proj_id, but besides that I think this should give you something to work with:

```
select
    b.FOLDERKEY + a.PROJ_ID PLANKEY
    ,b.FOLDERNAME
    ,a.PROJ_ID
    ,a.ACT_ID
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=1 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,0,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_JAN
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=2 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,1,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_FEB
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=3 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,2,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_MAR
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=4 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,3,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_APR
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=5 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,4,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_MAY
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=6 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,5,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_JUN
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=7 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,6,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_JUL
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=8 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,7,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_AUG
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=9 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,8,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_SEP
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=10 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,9,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end)  Y1_ACT_OCT
    ,sum(case when b.Base_Month<=11 and cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,10,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_NOV
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,11,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y1_ACT_DEC
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,12,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_JAN
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,13,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_FEB
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,14,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_MAR
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,15,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_APR
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,16,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_MAY
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,17,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_JUN
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,18,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_JUL
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,19,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_AUG
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,20,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_SEP
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,21,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_OCT
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,22,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_NOV
    ,sum(case when cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date)=dateadd(month,23,b.base_start) then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) Y2_ACT_DEC
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+2 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y3_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+3 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y4_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+4 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y5_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+5 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y6_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+6 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y7_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+7 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y8_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+8 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y9_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+9 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y10_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+10 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y11_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+11 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y12_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+12 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y13_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+13 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y14_FC]
    ,  sum(case when year(cast(a.fc_date+'.01' as date))=b.Base_Year+14 then a.AMT_USD else 0 end) [Y15_FC]
from [dbo].[STG_fcst] a
inner join (select FOLDERKEY,FOLDERNAME,FCST_BASE_DATE,CTR_STOP,year(FCST_BASE_DATE) Base_Year,dateadd(year,datediff(year,0,FCST_BASE_DATE),0) base_start,month(FCST_BASE_DATE) Base_Month from dbo.FOLDER_FCST_DT_XREF_VW) b
on
-- b.FOLDERKEY='AB05'and 
cast(a.FC_DATE+'.01' as date)>=b.FCST_BASE_DATE
group by b.FOLDERKEY + a.PROJ_ID 
,b.FOLDERNAME
    ,a.PROJ_ID
    ,a.ACT_ID
order by PROJ_ID,PLANKEY
```

Two things make it a little more complicated. I have to cast the FC_DATE to a date, and in stead of just using the BASE_DATE from the plan, i make a subselect where I calculate the base month as an int, and the start of the base year eg Jan 1, 2015.

Using this information I can fill out all the columns

Y1 Jan aggregates all rows with January dates in the base year, only if the base month is january.
Y1 Feb aggregates all rows with february dates in the base year, only if the base month is january or february
...
Y2 Jan aggregates all rows with january dates in the year following the base year
...
Y2 Dec aggregates all rows with december dates in the year following the base year

Y3_FC aggregates all dates with dates in the year of base year + 2
...
Y15_FC aggregates all dates with dates in the year of base year + 14